# Excel formula in openpyxl using python variable

Tags: python, excel-formula, openpyxl

I'm learning openpyxl to make my work easier and trying to find a way of using a variable in the formula. For example, there are 10 values from cell A1 to A10, and I want to put the average of these 10 values to A11 using the variable below.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb=load_workbook(filename='c:/average.xlsx')
ws=wb.active

b=10
ws.cell(11,1).value = "=AVERAGE(A1:A"b")"

wb.save('c:/average2.xlsx')
```

But the cell value of A11 is '=AVERAGE(A1:A)'. I tried "=AVERAGE(A1:A" b ")", "=AVERAGE(A1:A{b})", "=AVERAGE(A1:A{ b })" but nothing works. The purpose of this code is to do the same calculation in many cells like A11, B11, C11 etc.

I believe that the answer should be simple and found some previous questions related to similar issue but couldn't find the answer yet. FYI, I'm using python 2.7.18 and openpyxl 2.6.4. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update for Python 2.7:

You'll need to use one of the "old" methods, as f-strings aren't supported for Python 2.X...

```
b=10
ws.cell(11,1).value = "=AVERAGE(A1:A%d)" % b
```

---

You just need to properly format the string and inject the value of `b`. You can use "f-string" notation like so:

```
b=10
ws.cell(11,1).value = f"=AVERAGE(A1:A{b})"
```

That should do the trick.

For a deeper understanding (and alternative options), you could check out this reference: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/